# MSAL build error in Xcode 10.1 (iOS SDK 12.1)

Tags: ios, cocoapods, azure-ad-msal

Using pod with "platform :ios, '12.1'"
Deployment Target in Xcode set to 12.1

But I still get build errors where MSAL needs specific SDK 13 classes like: *Unknown type name 'ASAuthorizationController'*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though your app supports older versions of iOS, the latest MSAL version requires the iOS 13 SDK since it refers to iOS 13 symbols such as `ASAuthorizationController`

You either need to update to Xcode 11 or explicitly use an older version of the MSAL pod.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Where do I see which MSAL-version that matches a given iOS SDK? I have not been able to find this information.

Comment: I don't think it is stated explicitly anywhere. Version 1.1.0 introduced the iOS 13 SSO extension, so the previous version 1.0.7 is probably what you will have to use. Note that if you plan to submit to the App Store you must use Xcode 11

Comment: Perfect. Thanks, I know about Xcode 11/App store. This is only a proof of concept :-)